# Kotlin: Unresolved reference on custom class instance

Tags: class, kotlin, instantiation

I have a Kotlin class named `HttpsAuthenticator`. The file in which that class resides is also by the same name. `HttpsAuthenticator` has an inner class named XYZ. Here is the code:

```
public class HttpsAuthenticator
{
    public class XYZ{

    }
}
```

[image]

From another class, when I instantiate each of those two classes, `HttpsAuthenticator()` fails with the error `Unresolved reference`. What is the difference. How do I instantiate `HttpsAuthenticator`? Im absolutely new to Kotlin so I must be missing something basic I believe?

Comment: @Christilyn no actually. I did all that. Don't need a constructor. The solution was just to add `import HttpsAuthenticator`. That resolved the error, even though XYZ was exposed without import... Strange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up fixing it was simply adding `import HttpsAuthenticator`

Why XYZ was visible before that is beyond my comprehension at the moment. Im sure someone will come up with an explanation to this.